# PDF file not displayed in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, iframe, ejs

please help with the following issue,

I want to dynamic display some PDFs using node and ejs but I receive an error:

> Cannot GET /Documente/S231202-2.pdf -> for the
> btnUnu.addEventListener("click", toggle)      Cannot GET
> /Documente/S291040.pdf -> for the btnDoi.addEventListener("click",
> toggleDoi)

First, I use the next code in my main js file, app.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");

var routes = require("./routes");


var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3030);


app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Documente')));

app.use(routes)

app.listen(app.get("port"), function(){
    console.log("Serverul ruleaza la portul " + app.get("port"))
})
```

After that, in my ejs file, I used the next code:

```
<div class="Pagina2" style="padding: 15px;">  
        <iframe id="iframe" src="" width="200%" height="100%" style="border:3px solid rgb(68, 50, 88);"></iframe>
    </div>

    <script>

        const btnUnu = document.getElementById("eicunu");
        const btnDoi = document.getElementById("eicdoi");
        var iframeEl = document.getElementById("iframe");

        btnUnu.addEventListener("click", toggle)
        btnDoi.addEventListener("click", toggleDoi)

        function toggle(){
            iframeEl.src = "/Documente/S231202-2.pdf"
            // console.log("bine");
        }
        function toggleDoi(){
            iframeEl.src = "/Documente/S291040.pdf";
            // console.log("rau");
        }
    </script>
```

All is working well, just the PDF is not displayed.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why did you abbreviate the error message, which is most likely pointing to your issue?

Comment: Sorry, this is: Cannot GET /Documente/S231202-2.pdf // Cannot GET /Documente/S291040.pdf. I ll edit the post.

Comment: Right. So the files don't appear to exist where you think they do. I'll bet you cannot hit the files directly from the URL bar either, which means this likely has nothing to do with your HTML or Javascript, and everything to do with how your server-side directories and files are setup.

Comment: remove `Documente`: `iframeEl.src = "/S231202-2.pdf"` see: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: I added my full app.js file

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Documente` from iframe PDF file path, try this:

```
iframeEl.src = "/S231202-2.pdf"
```

---

You get that error because you're giving it incorrect path to the static PDF file.

When you set static files to this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Documente')));
```

it means that the requested PDF will be served like so: `req.url` + file, for example `http://localhost/file.pdf`, not `http://localhost/Documente/file.pdf`, which means you don't put `Documente` in the path on the front end, it's just `/`

But if you want to put `Documente` in the path, you'd need to add that path like so:

```
app.use('/Documente', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Documente')))
```

and then you can get PDF file like so:

```
iframeEl.src = "/Documente/S231202-2.pdf"
```

which is actually a virtual path so you can add anything instead of `Documente`, it doesn't need to correspond to the actual directory, since it's a virutal path.

for example:

```
app.use('/my-path', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Documente')))
```

and then

```
iframeEl.src = "/my-path/S231202-2.pdf"
```

See more here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html